# Problem mounting secondary disk in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mount, hard-drive

Title may be too generic (sorry about that) but I didn't see this exact problem in here, so here we go:

I have recently switched my pc from win10 to ubuntu and my second drive was in format Windows can read, I managed to make ubuntu read and edit it too, but this disk never mounts when boot up. I created a script to run some commands in which I reference the unmounted disk. When I boot up, there's a "second disk" which is empty, even before I execute any of these commands. When I use the Files interface of ubuntu to mount the disk it mount in `/media/<user>/<diskName>`. Why there's this ghost empty disk whenever I boot up instead of my disk that I have to mount manually?

In other words:
When I boot up there's a second disk mounted: `/media/<user>/<diskname>/<folder>/empty`
Instead of `/media/<user>/<diskname>/<my-data>`.
So I have to delete `/media/<user>/<diskname>/<empty>` then mount my second disk

The script I created purely run a docker inside the `/media/<user>/<diskname>/<my-data>/<mydockerproject>` and is ran by hand, not on boot up.
Why is this happening? How can I solve it?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** This is a partial / incomplete answer, as I don't have the time for a full one right now.

---

Normally you need to create an entry in the `/etc/fstab` file for each disk partition (on any disk) that you want to be mounted automatically at startup time.

**1. First create a mount point that's practical to use:**

Create a convenient permanent mount point (a path) for your data:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/my-data-lives-here
```

Grant ownership over it to your normal user, so that you can use it without admin privileges:

```
sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusername /mnt/my-data-lives-here
```

**2. Find your partitions' UUID:**

To find out the parameters you need to use, identify the partitions while your disk is connected to your computer (on the hardware level).

```
sudo lsblk -o UUID,NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,MODEL
```

(I prefer the `lsblk` command over `blkid`, because lsblk, with the above parameters displays the manufacturer and the brand of the disk, and visualises the hierarchy of the partitions on it; I find it helpful for visual type learners, like me.)

**3. Create the permanent entry in `/etc/fstab`**

To edit (and successfully save) `/etc/fstab` you will need sudo privileges.

E.g. with the `nano` editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

`/etc/fstab` will have some help at the top of it. Search the web (e.g. "fstab examples") for a number of examples about how an entry should look like, and what parameters to use.

Each new line represents another partition to mount.

This is the pattern of an entry:

```
<file system>   <mount point>   <type>   <options>   <dump>   <pass>
```

From here on, I suggest reading Ubuntu's introduction to fstab:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Comment: I can mark as ~ok~  Right Answer but can't upvote it, thanks, it worked!